# How to give notification after Hangfire is done

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, hangfire

Hi I have created a background job using `hangfire`in MVC 5. I send a notification that the background job has started but I don't know how to send a notification when the background job is Finished because my ActionResults method has returned.

The Controller

```
public ActionResult RunMedia(int ID)
{
    BackgroundJob.Enqueue<CrawlerSearchRequestModel>(x => x.StoreMedia(ID,"NaturalPerson"));
        obj
       {
         success: true
       };

return JSON(obj, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
}
```

The Ajax Call and Javascript notification

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("click", "#submitButton", function () {
        debugger;
        var userId = $(this).attr('userid')
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "../LemonCreditAuth/NaturalPerson/RunMedia",
            data: {
                ID: userId
            },
            success: function (data) {
                swal("Adverse Media!", "Adverse Media has started. After a 20 seconds please check the media case for updates", "success");
            },
            error: function (data, error) {
                swal("Adverse Media!", "Error ocurred while trying to run adverse media", "warning");
            }
        });
    });
```

Thanks

Comment: This is just a side issue, but returning a redirect from a method which is called via ajax makes no sense.

Comment: Use websockets, signalr

Comment: thanks I will set up signalr then try it out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others said you can use signalR or other protocols. To achive this, use IApplyStateFilter filter and implement OnStateApplied method of the interface.

```
public class YourAttribute : IApplyStateFilter{

    public void OnStateApplied(ApplyStateContext context, IWriteOnlyTransaction transaction)
    {
         if (context.NewState.IsFinal && context.NewState.Name == "Succeeded")
            //Send your message to client via signalR
    }}
```